# Load data into Java GUI

Tags: java, xml, javafx

I am working on a **Java** GUI which requires data to be read from an **XML** file. Ultimately i want to deliver a single .exe or .jar file where all the things you need are stored. These databases should get **automatically parsed**.

My question is: **Where** and in **which format** should I **store** the files so that they are always found automatically?

It should be as if the XML files are written in the sourcecode, but I don't think that this would be a good approach to this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If these files shall only be read, you may store them as resources in the class path. If the resource file is in the same directory as your class you may access the resource from within instances of that class like:

```
final URL myResource = getClass().getResource(nameOfFile);
final InputStream myResourceStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(nameOfFile);
```

Static access is possible like:

```
final URL myResource = MyClass.class.getResource(nameOfFile);
```

The *nameOfFile* may also contain a path to navigate withing the package structure:

```
final Resource myResource = getClass().getResource("subpackage/data.xml");
final Resource myResource = getClass().getResource("/com/myCompany/somePackage/data.xml");
```

And by the way: i recommend to use the java.**n**io.* classes to access files. One huge benefit is that this allows you to set custom file system implementations, if needed.

Comment: Thanks, this works fine when executed in my IDE, but does **not work** when building an **.exe** artifact and executing the .exe program (it cannot find the directory). Do you know a solution do this problem as well?

Comment: @lospollos I am not at all familiar with creating executables from java projects. Maybe your process does not include the resources into your compilation target. Maybe you missed an option for that? Or maybe you need to include a second file with your .exe?

Comment: Lets forget the .exe thing and assume I want to build a jar application. Do you know how I could set the path in the sourcecode in order to load the databases when delivering my tool? E.g. the databases are in a specific folder and the jar file is in another

Comment: If you mean providing the configuration of DB access, then a java properties file as resource may be a good approach. If you mean setting something like the windows PATH variable: for heaven's sake don't! The system configuration is something your application should not take control over.